# Ignore the errors className did not match Server and Client in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, getuikit

I'm using css framework and place cdns like this

```
//public <head> tag
<Helmet>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.6.15/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.6.15/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.6.15/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
</Helmet>
```

example inside the component

```
//Layout menu
<nav className="uk-navbar-container" data-uk-navbar="">
  <div className="uk-navbar-center">
    <ul className="uk-navbar-nav">
      <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/request">Request</Link></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
...
```

I'm getting the errors for example

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "uk-navbar-container uk-navbar" Client: "uk-navbar-container"
```

UIkit JS will adjust `class (className)` when the page load, and I want to keep that for animation stuff. Then I've tried

```
// just add "uk-navbar" fixed the errors
<nav className="uk-navbar-container uk-navbar" data-uk-navbar="">
  <div className="uk-navbar-center">
    <ul className="uk-navbar-nav">
      <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/request">Request</Link></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
...
```

But in reality there are so many to look up to fix the errors

How to turn off (ignore) the errors (warning) in Gatsby?

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby, by default, comes with a default ESLint configuration. As you can see from the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/eslint/):

> Gatsby ships with a built-in ESLint setup. For most users, our
> built-in ESLint setup is all you need. If you know however that you’d
> like to customize your ESLint config e.g. your company has their own
> custom ESLint setup, this shows how this can be done

To disable the ESLint, just create an empty `.eslintrc` file in the root of your project.

Comment: Thanks, but still showing the errors. I did `npm i eslint-config-react-app` and created `.eslintrc` accordingly to the docs. are there process I still be missing?